# Single post works but looped post returns 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

When I add an image one by one it saves and returns a 200 response. But when I try to convert it to a loop it returns a 500 error. Both ways the image does save to s3 so I am not sure where the 500 error is coming from

working code in postsController@store

```
        $uploadedFile = request()->images[0];
        $uploadedFile->store('uploads', 's3');
        return['hi', request('images')];
```

non working loop

```
          foreach(request('images') as $image){
            $imagePath= $image->store('uploads', 's3');

        };
        return 'hi';
```

Ive referred to the object as both request('images') and request()->images, I think both are the same and should produce the same output.

If i click on the error in the network tab i get this

```
    "message": "Call to a member function store() on null",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
    "file": "/Users/raj/challenges/instagrizzleTWC/instagrizzle/app/Http/Controllers/PostsController.php",
    "line": 25,
    "trace": [
        {
            "function": "store",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\PostsController",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

Here is my data object from vue

```
        data: function () {
            return{
                image_count:1,
                max_uploads:5,
                totalsteps:4,
                step:1,
                images:[
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                ],
                caption:"new post",
                starting_bid:"10",
                bid_increment:"10",
                end_time:"11-30-2019 12:11:00",
                bin:"100",
                snipe:true,
                snipe_time:"5",
                autoremove_bids:true,
                csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),

            }
        },
```

and here is my submit method to create formData and send to back end

```
            handleSubmit: function()
            {
                const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}
                const post_data = new FormData();
                post_data.append('images[]', this.images[0]['image_path']);
                post_data.append('images[]', this.images[1]['image_path']);
                post_data.append('images[]', this.images[2]['image_path']);
                post_data.append('images[]', this.images[3]['image_path']);
                post_data.append('images[]', this.images[4]['image_path']);

                axios.post('/p', post_data, config)
                  .then(function (response) {
                    console.log('response', response);
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
            },
```

Im thinking it could have to do with the csrf token but that should fail with the origial post?

Comment: Does it save ALL images? Then my guess is there is an empty `images[]` element at the end. What does `dd(request('images'));` output?

Comment: aaah hmm that could be it. so another issue ive been having for some reason dd() isnt working like it does with blade templates. I thought it might be a conflict with vue?

Comment: yup that was it, Thanks Thomas!

Comment: Happy to help .

Answer (score 0):

Images is trying to post empty objects, add an if statement:

```
        $image_arr = [];

        foreach(request('images') as $image){
            if($image != null){
                $imagePath = $image->store('uploads', 's3');
                array_push($image_arr, $imagePath);
            }

        };
        return ['Image Array', $image_arr];
```